# Meteor.js - Create an auto increment field on method

Tags: javascript, meteor

here's method "saveProject" that writes data collection "Projects".

```
Meteor.methods({
  'saveProject': function (project) {
    check(project.name, String);
    currentId = Projects.findOne({},{sort:{id:-1}}).id || 1;
    project.id = currentId + 1;
    project.userId = Meteor.userId();
    project.dateentered = new Date();
    project.lastupdate = new Date();
    if (!project.datedue) {
      project.datedue = new Date();
    }
    project.invited = [];
    return Projects.insert(project);
  }
});
```

This code creates a given named "id" and assigns automatic numbering of saved "projects".

```
currentId = Projects.findOne({},{sort:{id:-1}}).id || 1;
project.id = currentId + 1;
```

The problem is that this code works only when the collection is saved first "project". How to modify this code to work longer while writing the first draft to the collection of data "Projects"

Comment: Can you add a dollar sign to sort, like so $sort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to create a separate collection for auto-incrementing sequence fields.

For example:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        Counters._ensureIndex({"type": 1});
        if (Counters.find({type: "projectId"}).count() == 0) Counters.insert({type: "projectId", seq: 0});
        Projects.insert({seq: getNextSequence("projectId"), name: "Project 1"});
        Projects.insert({seq: getNextSequence("projectId"), name: "Project 2"});
        Projects.insert({seq: getNextSequence("projectId"), name: "Project 3"});
        Projects.insert({seq: getNextSequence("projectId"), name: "Project 4"});
    });
}

Projects = new Mongo.Collection("projects");
Counters = new Mongo.Collection("counters");

getNextSequence = function (name) {
    Counters.update({type: name}, {$inc: {seq: 1}});
    var ret = Counters.findOne({type: name});
    return ret.seq;
};
```

Output:

```
{ "_id" : "vMmxNRCxroicxYftf", "seq" : 1, "name" : "Project 1" }
{ "_id" : "g8EMSooQK7JQ8bTNL", "seq" : 2, "name" : "Project 2" }
{ "_id" : "RZw3JxnMohinJ5x3g", "seq" : 3, "name" : "Project 3" }
{ "_id" : "BEoyoo3jJPRCgjTuc", "seq" : 4, "name" : "Project 4" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
if (Projects.find({}).count() === 0) {
      currentId = 0;
      project.id = currentId + 1;
    } else {
      currentId = Projects.findOne({},{sort:{id:-1}}).id || 1;
      project.id = currentId + 1;
    }
```

Comment: please write a brief description as to how this resolves the issue. Welcome to Stack Overflow, recommended reading [answer].